# Designing data source agnostic models

Tags: typescript, design-patterns, architecture

I'm working on a full stack Typescript app, and am trying to

1. Keep all of the models and services logic separated from any backing data source
2. Keep data and behavior separated (i.e. method-less models)

But I'm having a hard time figuring out how to design these models when it comes to relationships.

Right now I have a `core` package, that exports some interfaces

```
interface Item {
  id: string;
  text: string;
  idProject: string;
}

interface Project {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  idSource: string;
}

interface Source {
  type: 'rss' | 'api';
  name: string;
}

interface ItemService {
  get(id: string): Promise<Item>
}

interface ProjectService {
  get(id: string): Promise<Project>
}

interface SourceService {
  get(id: string): Promise<Source>
}

interface ProjectItemLoaderService {
  constructor();
  loadItems(project: Project, source: Source): Promise<Item[]>;
}
```

and then in my `server` package, I use them like this

```
get('/project/:idProject/items', ({ idProject }) => {
  const project = projectService.get(idProject);
  const source = sourceService.get(project.idSource);
  const items = projectItemLoaderService.loadItems(project, source);
  ...
})
```

But from what I've been reading on this topic of well-abstracted models (DDD, hexagonal architecture), my models shouldn't be referring to relationships via ID, but should include the actual model, since things like ID are a storage-concept, and not a domain concept.

```
interface Item {
  id: string;
  text: string;
  project: Project
}

interface Project {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  source: Source
}

interface Source {
  type: 'rss' | 'api';
  name: string;
}

...

interface ProjectItemLoaderService {
  constructor();
  loadItems(project: Project): Promise<Item[]>;
}

...

get('/project/:idProject/items', ({ idProject }) => {
  const project = projectService.get(idProject);
  // Project already includes the Source model, not need to load it
  const items = projectItemLoaderService.loadItems(project);
  ...
})
```

This is more convenient to not have to constantly be loading nested models, but seems like it could get out of handle easily as the nesting gets deeper and deeper. The Project model should actually have a `items: Item[]` property, which could take a quite a long time to populate based on the backing storage. And it would then be cyclical, which is a whole other issue.

I'm basically looking for any advice on making data-agnostic models, and how services that handle those models should be given access its relationships. Maybe doing this sort of thing without going full DDD (use cases, commands, all that) is just not very feasible, and I should just be using source-couple ORM objects, but I really do like the idea of having the business logic layer being decoupled from the underlying data source.

Answer (score 0):

First: yes, it is better to have a graph of domain objects instead of maps with id. It's much easier to manipulate, to understand and implement relationships, and to maintain.

Second: you must not load the whole data of your domain in your application. And when loading an object, you don't have to load the whole tree of dependencies.

- It will consume memory,
- take a very long time to load for info you don't need,
- and will quickly be stale because of other users operations

**--> Make services that load only the objects and nested objects you need for a page or an operation.**

For example, for a list you often only have to load the objects of the list, but on the detail page you will want to load and display the associated children for 1 or 2 more level of depth.

(You will later think about which data may be re-used often and optimize with cache)

Comment: But what about types these models? Say if `project` will only be loaded onto an `Item` sometimes, I would have to type it as `project: Project | undefined`. And then whenever I have a service that depends on `Item` it will have to be doing constant null checks to determine if `project` is present or not. When practically, that service should only ever be called with an `Item` that has `project` populated.

Comment: Yes... but the alternative with IDs is worse. However, when you know you will always need the relationship, you can make the field mandatory and load it systematically.

Comment: NB: Perhaps an item can exist without a project anyway? And do you need the link from item to project if you have from project to item already?